# I can't get scrollTop() to work, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to add "Back to top" button to my website. It is supposed to show up when user scrolls to the bottom of my website. But it won't fade in. It just won't. I have no idea what's wrong, I checked my code and everything should be working fine, but it doesn't. Back to top button codes are simple and so is mine... I don't know, just look at the code.

index.html - temporary I have my CSS styles here also:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title>Clockwork</title>

    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Righteous|Titillium+Web:400,400italic,700,700italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="orange.ico">

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="http://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="http://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <style>
      body {
        background: url('retro-vintage-pink-city.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
        -webkit-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        -o-background-size: cover;
        background-size: cover;
        height: 100%;
        color: white;
        font-family: 'Titillium Web', 'Courier New', sans-serif;
      }
      html {
        height: 100%;
      }
      .home-section {
        height: 100%;
      }
      .about-section {
        height: 80%;
        padding-top: 24px;
        text-align: justify;
        background: rgba(16,16,16,0.9);
        border-top: 2px solid white;
        border-bottom: 2px solid white;
        box-shadow: 0 0 20px #000;
      }
      .media-section {
        height: 100%;
        padding-top: 150px;
        text-align: center;
      }
      .press-section {
        height: 100%;
        padding-top: 150px;
        text-align: center;
      }
      .buy-section {
        height: 100%;
        padding-top: 150px;
        text-align: center;
      }
      .paragraphs {
        font-size: 16px;
        padding-top: 12px;
        padding-bottom: 12px;
        padding-left: 16px;
        padding-right: 16px;
      }
      .logo {
        margin: 0 auto;
        transform: translateY(50%);
      }
      .btn-md, .btn-md:hover, .btn-md:active, .btn-md:focus {
        padding: 12px 24px;
        border: none;
        border-radius: 0px;
        box-shadow: 0 0 28px #000;
        color: #fff;
        background: linear-gradient(45deg, #005387 0%, #005387 39%, #007387 100%);
        font-size: 20px;
        font-weight: bold;
      }
      #return-to-top {
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 20px;
        right: 20px;
        background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
        background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        display: block;
        text-decoration: none;
        -webkit-border-radius: 35px;
        -moz-border-radius: 35px;
        border-radius: 35px;
        -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
        -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
        -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease;
        -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
        transition: all 0.3s ease;
      }
      #return-to-top i {
        color: #fff;
        margin: 0;
        position: relative;
        left: 16px;
        top: 13px;
        font-size: 19px;
        -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
        -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
        -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease;
        -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
        transition: all 0.3s ease;
      }
      #return-to-top:hover {
        background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
      }
      #return-to-top:hover i {
        color: #fff;
        top: 5px;
      }
  </style>
  </head>
  <body id="page-top" data-spy="scroll">
    <a href="home" id="return-to-top"><i class="icon-chevron-up"></i></a>

    <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <section id="home" class="home-section">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-12">
            <img class="img-responsive logo" src="logo.png" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>

    <section id="about" class="about-section">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="paragraphs">
              <p style="text-align: center; font-size: 42px; font-weight: bold;">About</p>
              <p style="text-align: center;"><strong>Lurk into the story and let it fill you up with an indescribable joy of exploring the fantastic and yet sometimes mysterious world of <span style="color: rgb(255, 163, 0)">Clockwork!</span></strong></p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-3">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="anna.png" />
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-9">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-lg-12 paragraphs">
                <p>Set in a vastly mind-opening era of 60s the game features an <span style="color: rgb(255, 163, 0); font-weight: bold;">ensemble cast</span> of various and colorful characters with each one having his or her own motivations, plans and goals. Join them in their unknowingly, but surprisingly funny venture which would eventually lead to a truly astonishing final in... Well, let's leave that for you to discover! As it will come to the end of the story, all our heroes' paths will cross and therefore they'll together try to save us all from an unexpected, but sadly <span style="color: rgb(255, 163, 0); font-weight: bold;">inevitable doom</span>. This is the event that will be <span style="color: rgb(255, 163, 0); font-weight: bold;">remembered!</span></p>
                <p>On their way stands a whole army of many, many, many very smart, as it often occurs, evil-geniuses and also a bunch of ordinary morons who shall do nothing, but only slow our heroes down. Let them not stop our <span style="color: rgb(255, 163, 0); font-weight: bold;">salvation!</span></p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-lg-12 paragraphs text-center" style="transform: translateY(50%);">
                <a href="#buy" class="page-scroll btn btn-md">BUY</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>

    <section id="media" class="media-section">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-12">
            <h1>Media</h1>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>

    <section id="press" class="press-section">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-12">
            <h1>Press</h1>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>

    <section id="buy" class="buy-section">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-12">
            <h1>Buy</h1>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>

    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Scrolling Nav JavaScript -->
    <script src="jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scrolling-nav.js"></script>
    <script src="js/index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

index.js:

```
// ===== Scroll to Top ==== 
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#return-to-top").hide();

$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 50) {        // If page is scrolled more than 50px
        $('#return-to-top').fadeIn(200);   // Fade in the arrow
    } else {
        $('#return-to-top').fadeOut(200);   // Else fade out the arrow
    }
});
$('#return-to-top').click(function() {      // When arrow is clicked
    $('body,html').animate({
        scrollTop : 0                       // Scroll to top of body
    }, 500);
    return false;
});
});
```

Here's jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/kjgeaeqc/

Comment: Will wait for jsfiddle to try something.

Comment: Looks working: http://jsfiddle.net/ymbtcn1a/

Comment: same here @Justas https://jsfiddle.net/pu44z4yL/

Comment: @mentor93 check your console after pressing "Back to top" button.

Comment: check if index.js is getting loaded, perhaps the path is wrong

Comment: Check your console (F12 -> Click on Console).  Are all of these files on your server: jquery.easing.min.js, scrolling-nav.js, js/index.js?

Comment: @Justas: The point is that Back to top button doesn't show up, so I cannot click on it...

index.js loads correctly. When I checked console it shows: "TypeError: $(...).offset(...) is undefined" error in scrolling-nav.js file. I think that has nothing to do with my back to top button.

Comment: @mentor93 I guess the reason is you are not including JQuerry Library to your file.

Comment: @divy3993: Do you mean index.js file? Because I included jquerry to index.html.

Comment: No the `jquery.js` or `jquery-min.js` file. The library i am talking about.

Comment: Based on the fiddle you provided, I think my answer is wrong as I misunderstood since the **fiddle does not include a jquery file**. As @divy3993 mentioned, you need to include `jquery` file for your code to work.

Comment: I guess the actual **reason is** you **not including that library within your `<head>...</head>` part of file.** I suggest you to include `
   `<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>` within your `<head>...</head>`

Comment: You mean that I should include jquery,min.js in head part? Hm, I'll try that, but on "Getting started" on Bootstrap they include jquery inside body, not head, that's why I did that, too.

Comment: Still doesn't work...

Comment: Not an option. Wait download this [file](http://www.divyashah.in/stackoverflow/pages/mentor93.html). And let me know if it does'nt work.

Comment: Your file works, but the script doesn't work on my website. Download this rar: http://www.filedropper.com/website_2 and please tell me what's wrong there, I'm out of ideas.

Comment: Ok i got the reason and that is your file `scrolling-nav.js` getting somehow conflicitng with your `JQuery Library`. Comment `<!--script src="scrolling-nav.js"></script-->' for a while and try again. It must work.

Comment: Yes, it works now. Thank you!

Comment: Actually your `scrolling-nav.js` and `index.js` were conflicting. Sorry not the JQuery Library.

Comment: Nevertheless, it works now. Thank you once again!